# Visual studio C++ plugin that formats the code following some rules

Tags: c++, visual-studio, plugins, code-formatting

Somebody knows if exists some plugin for visual studio C++ that acts like the formatter and clean up profiles of Eclipse?

I want something that formats my code following some predefined rules like:

- put const in function when possible
- don't allow empty lines
- don't allow functions do pass 100 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with such utilities, but you can search for code cleanup add-ons at the Visual Studio Gallery: http://msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio

Comment: Wow, I had not thought of that, haha. I searched and found two extensions, now I'll try them, thanks.